# Use of a user defined section name [ __attribute__((section(“name”)) ]

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linker

I do have some doubts about **attribute**((section("name")) .What is the real use of defining a user defined .section? Is there any examples to shows how it is useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defined sections are particularly useful for embedded systems that feature multiple memory banks. With the help of a linker script, these sections can be used to place code and data in certain memory banks and at certain locations; this is e.g. important to ensure correct placement of interrupt vectors.
For example, [this line](https://github.com/Erlkoenig90/ArmAsmTutorial/blob/93e79a24d491cb77e9197273c401967b3392e7f8/vectortable.S#L13) places the following data into a custom section (in assembly language, but it's equivalent to the section attribute), such that the [linker script](https://github.com/Erlkoenig90/ArmAsmTutorial/blob/93e79a24d491cb77e9197273c401967b3392e7f8/stm32f103rb.ld#L8) can then put it at the beginning of flash memory.

For ordinary standard-compliant C and C++ applications this is usually unnecessary, which is why the attribute is a non-standard extension.

Comment: what is the advantage of placing a custom section in a memory bank. Will that increase the performance (or access time of the memory area)?

Comment: That depends a lot on the concrete system. There might be performance improvements (e.g. putting performance critical code in specific fast memory blocks), or some memory banks might have special properties (e.g. battery backup), or you might want to put code in one memory bank while that code overwrites the other bank (typical embedded bootloader), or you just want to keep some related functions closely together for better cache efficiency.

Comment: The C runtime also uses this in cooperation with the compiler to compose data structures that span multiple source files that are needed for initialization of global variables. Again, highly platform-specific.

Comment: I would rather say that for embedded systems more useful feature is to have an ability to reclaim memory used by some sections when they are no longer needed.

Comment: @0andriy You mean by overlapping multiple sections?

Comment: How do custom sections help that?

Comment: If dynamic loader, which has been used to run the executable, has this feature, than it may unmap corresponding pages and return them to the kernel, i.o.w. OS may **reclaim** them. This is highly being used in Linux kernel itself which is important to the *embedded* environment. P.S. Don't forget to add @0andriy to the comments to give to opponent an opportunity to notice it.

Comment: @0andriy how does the dynamic linker know which pages to unmap, and why isn't `-ffunction-sections` sufficient?

Comment: Linker? Linker has nothing to do with that. Loader does. It relies on special name or name pattern of the section.

Comment: @0andriy On Linux, dynamic linker and loader are [the same thing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). Is there a documentation for the pattern?